# no ground bar in electrical subpanel

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

I found that the subpanel in our newly built home may not have ground bar, though it has neutral bar. I attached photos for confirmation. Please let me know if there is any code violation. The house was built this year and located in California.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

One more image showing where the big wires enter the panel box:
[image: image4]

Comment: Can you post a photo that clearly shows where the big wires coming into the subpanel enter the box?

Comment: There is a ground bar. It's behind the black wires in the bottom-right corner of the last pic.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have attached one photo. Not sure if it is a good enough angle.

Comment: @brhans Good catch! There is indeed a bar buried behind all those wires.

Answer (score 3):

### There is a ground after all

The ground bars on most loadcenters, when fitted, are located on the far left and right sides of the enclosure, so they often get buried behind wiring in the gutter spaces, and this appears to be the case in your installation.  (In your third photo, you can just see one peeking out from behind the wiring in the bottom right-hand corner of the picture.)

Your fourth photo also shows the bare fat wire that is the ground in the feeder cable (what appears to be a type SE-R cable), running off what I presume is a lug on the left-hand ground bar, and the empty hole on the left-hand side of the neutral jumper bar, next to the red wire, is *correct* for a subpanel (it is where the bonding screw goes when this panel is used as a main).